# Interactive correlation matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I want to plot correlation matrix in such a sense that it should be interactive and show both, correlation values and corresponding p-values in ggplot2 or plot_ly.

I have tried the following code.

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(plotly)
    library(reshape)
    library(Hmisc)

    x <- Seatbelts
    y <- as.matrix(x)
    rt <- rcorr(y)
    mtlr <- melt(rt$r)
    mtlp <- melt(rt$P) 
    gx <- ggplot(mtl, aes(X1, X2, fill = value)) + geom_tile() + 
      scale_fill_gradient(low = "cyan",  high = "red")
    ggplotly(gx)
```

I want to show "mtlp" value in the same plot.

Can anyone help?

Comment: As a first step you can try to merge the two data.frames `mtlr`and `mtlp` into one. Look for the `merge()` function or the `_join()` functions in package `dplyr`.

Comment: its not the issue to merge the values. rt <- rcorr(y) already contains both data-frames. problem is how i can call both values (correlation & p-value) when i hover my cursor in a single cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add your p-values as a `label` or `text` which will then appear in your hovertext.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(reshape)
library(Hmisc)

x <- Seatbelts
y <- as.matrix(x)
rt <- rcorr(y)
mtlr <- melt(rt$r)
mtlp <- melt(rt$P) 
p.value <- mtlp$value
gx <- ggplot(mtlr, aes(X1, X2, fill = value, label=p.value)) + geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "cyan",  high = "red")
ggplotly(gx)
```

Comment: thanks. you solved my problem. i just modified a little and got one better result.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to merge the two melted data.frames back together, then use the `text` aesthetic to add to the tooltip.

I re-did the melt using `reshape2` (instead of `reshape`) and set value names to make the merge easier

```
mtlr <- melt(rt$r, value.name = "Correlation")
mtlp <- melt(rt$P, value.name = "P-Value")

mtl <-
  merge(mtlr, mtlp)
```

Then, make the plot -- note that you can use anything you want in the `text` aesthetic, and I often use it to change the layout/presentation of the tooltip (and then only display the `text` tooltip)

```
gx <-
  ggplot(mtl
         , aes(Var1, Var2
               , fill = Correlation
               , text = paste("P-val = ", round(`P-Value`, 4)))) +
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "cyan",  high = "red")
ggplotly(gx)
```